# Dynamic default operator for Simple Query String Query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to specify `default_operator` more dynamically base on the user search input?

I want to achieve something like this:

1. when user does not put any special chars (`+`, `|`, `-`, `"`, etc) then I would like to set `default_operator := OR`
2. but when user puts any of these special chars the `default_operator` should be set to `AND`

Is this possible on Elasticsearch side?

Comment: Wouldn't this just be done on the client side? Maybe regex/replace with AND?

Comment: Yes, on client side it is obvious. But I'm curious if it is possible on ES side.